# Calling static class outside of namespace

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

Inside a class "cl1" in the namespace "space1", there is the function "fctn1", and inside it I want to call the static method "fctn2" from the class "cl2". The class cl2 is not inside any namespaces.

```
<?php
namespace space1;

class cl1
{
    public function fctn1()
    {
        cl2::fctn2();
    }
}
```

```
<?php

class cl2
{
    public static function fctn2()
    {
        // stuff here
    }
}
```

How can I call fctn2 inside the fctn1 on PHP?

I tryied simply calling the method inside the class just like shown in the code on the question.

Comment: Prepend a backslash to address the global namespace: `\cl2::fetch2();`

Answer (score 1):

[Honk der Hase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2443226/honk-der-hase) gave a satisfactory answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74212158/calling-static-class-outside-of-namespace/74212238#comment131025282_74212158):

> Prepend a backslash to address the global namespace:
>
> ```
> \cl2::fetch2();
> ```